# PIC32MX Controller UART1 receive not working

Tags: c, embedded, uart, microchip, pic32

I am working with PIC32MX350F128L.The uart1 which is PIN 22 for (TX) and pin 20 for (RX). I am able to send a character but not able to receive any character.Below is the code attached.

Please do have a look at code and suggest some changes ?

```
void init_uart();

void UART1PutChar(unsigned char Ch);

char  SerialReceive_1();

void main()

{

    char res;
    OSCCON=0x00002200; //ask settings clock





    ANSELBbits.ANSB3 = 0;
    ANSELBbits.ANSB5 = 0;


    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 0;

    PORTCbits.RC3 = 1;
    PORTCbits.RC4 = 1;


    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0;  //in controler tx
    TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 1; // in controller RX     



    U1RXR=0x08;
    RPB3R=0x03;



        init_uart() ;
     UART1PutChar('T');

    while(1)

    {

    res =  SerialReceive_1();

   UART1PutChar(res);


    }
}

void init_uart() 
{
     U1MODEbits.ON =1;

    U1BRG = 25; 


    U1STA=0x1400;

   IFS1bits.U1RXIF = 0;
   IFS1bits.U1TXIF = 0 ;

   return;
}



void UART1PutChar(unsigned char Ch)
{


    while(U1STAbits.UTXBF == 1);
     U1TXREG=Ch;  

     return ;

}



char  SerialReceive_1()    
{

    char buf1;



     while(!U1STAbits.URXDA);  
         buf1  = U1RXREG;    


        return buf1;


}
```

Regards

Comment: SO is no debugging service!

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://electrosome.com/uart-pic-microcontroller-mplab-xc8/) you could find all flag that enables UART on PIC microcontrollers.

Comment: read from portbits write to latbits. Use symbolic constants as much as possible. (for pps and bit registers) or set individual, named bits.